# Find all records that match a GROUP BY result HAVING count > 1 in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

The GROUP BY and HAVING isn't the hard part. This query results the summary:

```
SELECT date, account, amount, COUNT(1) AS num
FROM "transactions"
GROUP BY date, account, amount
HAVING num > 1
```

Something like:

```
date        account    amount  num
2011-02-07  580416690  -6.4    2
2011-07-19             -50.0   2
2011-08-29  2445588    -22.0   2
2011-12-16  265113334  -0.1    3
```

But I dont want the summary (4 records). I want all the relevant records (so 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 = 9 records). If the GROUP BY was on 1 column, that wouldn't be hard either, but with 3 columns...

How do I get the actual records with those values? 1 query must be possible. Do I need 3 subqueries?

Comment: Join back to the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to join back to `transactions`

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions t JOIN 
(
  SELECT date, account, amount
    FROM transactions
   GROUP BY date, account, amount
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) d
  ON (t.date = d.date
 AND t.account = d.account
 AND t.amount = d.amount) OR
     (t.date = d.date
 AND t.account IS NULL AND d.account IS NULL
 AND t.amount = d.amount)
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a0592/5)** demo

Comment: That doesn't work with `NULL`... `account` is sometimes `NULL` and those must match in `t` and `d` too. Maybe it's SQLite, maybe it's normal, but apparently `NULL != NULL`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' What's the design error? My db having NILs? Grouping by NILs? Quering on NIL columns?

Comment: @Rudie: Allowing NULL for account numbers sounds like a design error.

Comment: @peterm: Might be better to `coalesce(account, 'no account')` rather than add conditions to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Rudie See the update. Although I have to admin that having NULLs for `account` seems to be at least strange...

Comment: If I don't know the account no, its a NIL. Sometimes I don't. Sounds sensible to me. Could have been empty string. Probably easier in hindsight.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' `COALESCE()` might be used as well. Although it's a function call for each row so hard to say what is better.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' COALESCE! You win.